# Extreme Value Theory - Determining the positive normalising constant in the Extremal Types Theorem

Tags: extreme-value, inequality

I am working through the following question and cannot seem to work out how the final result is obtained from the last inequality involving $a_n$. Can someone shed some light?[image]